# which one is better approach one large svc file or multiple small svc files in WCF

Tags: wcf, svc

I have one data intensive application where in I have one svc file which creates the C# reference file roughly of size 3mb and around 70 endpoints. Will it be good to break them in multiple svc files or is it ok to have one single svc file?